# Существует ли Deep learning framework для больших размеров моделей в GPU?

Tags: framework

Современные фреймворки такие как torch и tensorflow могут загрузить и обсчитать модель в GPU только соразмерную свободной памяти GPU. 
Есть ли такой фреймворк, чтобы загружал и обсчитывал в GPU любую большую модель частями?